# Repeating rows in a DataFrame based on a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe now：

```
   class1  class2  value  value2
0       1       0      1       4
1       2       1      2       3
2       2       0      3       5
3       3       1      4       6
```

I want to repeat rows and insert an increment column in the same amount according to the difference between `value` and `value2`. I want to get the dataframe should like this:

```
    class1  class2  value  value2  value3
0        1       0      1       4       1
1        1       0      1       4       2
2        1       0      1       4       3
3        1       0      1       4       4
4        2       1      2       3       2
5        2       1      2       3       3
6        2       0      3       5       3
7        2       0      3       5       4
8        2       0      3       5       5
9        3       1      4       6       4
10       3       1      4       6       5
11       3       1      4       6       6
```

I tried it like：

```
def func(x):
    copy = x.copy()
    num = x.value2+1-x.value
    return pd.concat([copy]*num.values[0])
df= df.groupby(['class1','class2']).apply(lambda x:func(x))
```

But there will be a oredr problem that leads me to not know how to add column `value3`. And I'd like to have an elegant way of doing it.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute the difference and call `Index.repeat`:

```
idx = df.index.repeat(df.value2 - df.value + 1)
```

Now, either use `reindex`:

```
df = df.reindex(idx).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Or `loc`:

```
df = df.loc[idx].reset_index(drop=True)
```

And you get

```
df
    class1  class2  value  value2
0        1       0      1       4
1        1       0      1       4
2        1       0      1       4
3        1       0      1       4
4        2       1      2       3
5        2       1      2       3
6        2       0      3       5
7        2       0      3       5
8        2       0      3       5
9        3       1      4       6
10       3       1      4       6
11       3       1      4       6
```

---

For the second part of your question, you'll need `groupby.cumcount`:

```
s = idx.to_series()
df['value3'] =  df['value'] + s.groupby(idx).cumcount().values
df
    class1  class2  value  value2  value3
0        1       0      1       4       1
1        1       0      1       4       2
2        1       0      1       4       3
3        1       0      1       4       4
4        2       1      2       3       2
5        2       1      2       3       3
6        2       0      3       5       3
7        2       0      3       5       4
8        2       0      3       5       5
9        3       1      4       6       4
10       3       1      4       6       5
11       3       1      4       6       6
```

Comment: Whether `df['value3'] = (
    s.groupby(idx).cumcount() + s.groupby(idx).ngroup() + 1
).values` should be modified to be `df['value3'] = s.groupby(idx).cumcount().values + df['value']`.Because `value`  is not a increment column.

Comment: @giser_yugang Oh, sure. If that's what you meant, then by all means. See edit?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sequence of things that would get you the desired output:

```
df.join(df
        .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(range(x.value, x.value2+1)), axis=1)
        .stack().astype(int)
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=1)
        .to_frame('value3')).reset_index(drop=1)

Out[]:
    class1  class2  value  value2  value3
0        1       0      1       4       1
1        1       0      1       4       2
2        1       0      1       4       3
3        1       0      1       4       4
4        2       1      2       3       2
5        2       1      2       3       3
6        2       0      3       5       3
7        2       0      3       5       4
8        2       0      3       5       5
9        3       1      4       6       4
10       3       1      4       6       5
11       3       1      4       6       6
```

Comment: join, apply, AND stack?

Comment: Sure: `apply()` to create the ranges, `stack()` to flatten and `join()` to bring it back into the original `df`.

Comment: Oh, it works all right... just not on anything over a few hundred rows without possibly freezing ;-)